# Error 404 en petición tipo PATCH

Tags: laravel

Tengo un error 404 al intentar modificar una notificacion usando el metodo PATCH. Segun lo que veo el id que paso a travez de la ruta es muy largo por lo que me da un error. He probado poniendo un id manual y funciona.

Esta es la ruta en el navegador:

http://app.test/noticaciones/3843480d-e9a0-479f-aace-36442137bdcd

Este es mi formulario:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('notifications.read', $unreadNotification->id) }}">
                                        @method('PATCH')
                                        @csrf
                                        <div class="float-right">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">X</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

Esta es mi ruta:

```
Route::patch('/noticaciones/{id}', 'NotificationsController@read')->name('notifications.read');
```

Comment: podrias agregar el controlador? o que error marca el debug?

Comment: @Bryro es que ni siquiera llega hasta el controlador, la ruta lanza el error 404 al instante.

Comment: Ese form se envía al presionar el botón o estás usando javascript?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ si, al presionar se envía ese form, si te fijas lo que hace es enviar el id a través de la ruta